# Hexagon object not centered on Apple Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I generated this Hexagon using http://csshexagon.com/, and I'm using it on my personal website. But for some reason, it seems to center on all other browsers except for Apple Safari (on macOS and iOS).

I tried applying most of the CSS properties I know that generally center things, but it doesn't seem to work on this particular Hexagon (maybe because of the way it is coded).

**Chrome on macOS Sierra**
[image: Amruth Pillai - Chrome on macOS Sierra]

**Safari on macOS Sierra**
[image: Safari on macOS Sierra]

You can play around with the live demo of the website here: **http://www.amruthpillai.com/**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: safari version ??

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.3)